# Shell/Bash - want to map array of file to a set of numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line

I got a file with an array of names and I got a other file with multiple series of numbers, counting up from 1 to the length of the array. They have the same length, except the last digit of the series is always a 0. Those numbers can start with a "-", then the current element should not get mapped to it, or it is just the pure number.

Now I want to map the first element of the array to the number 1, second element to 2, ... . Here is a example:

The **first File** contains:

```
['aaaaa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'dd', 'eeeee']
```

And the **other File** contains:

```
-1 2 -3 -4 -5 0
1 -2 3 4 -5 0
1 2 -3 4 5 0
```

**Desired Output:**

```
bbb
aaaaa, cccc, dd
aaaaa, bbb, dd, eeeee
```

**Note:** The Format of the output has not to be in this exact format. I want to have this fully in bash/shell and don't use other python, c, ... scripts.

**EDIT:**

I haven't look for awhile because I thought noone would reply this fast. In the mean time I wrote my own code for this. Here you can see the Final result...

... assuming that the **first file** is called *tmp.txt* and the **second file** is called *tmp_num.txt*:

```
NAMES=()
for elem in $(cat tmp.txt | sed "s/,//g; s/[][]//g; s/'//g")
do
    NAMES+=($elem)
done

for number in $(cat tmp_num.txt)
do
    if [ "$number" -eq "0" ]; then
        echo 
        continue
    fi

    if [[ ${number:0:1} != "-" ]] ; 
        
        then
            number=$((number-1))
            echo -n ${NAMES[${number}]}" ";
    fi
done
```

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried so far, and the (right/wrong) results said code is generating

Comment: Sorry @markp-fuso I saw you commet to late. I startet after I found some good approches and then I had the final code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Where `Input_file` is your keys file and your valFile is your `other file`(mentioned by OP in question).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=", "
}
FNR==NR{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    match($i,/\047[^\047]*/)
    value[++count]=substr($i,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
  }
  next
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!=0 && $i!~/^-/){
      val=(val?val OFS:"")value[$i]
    }
  }
  print val
  val=""
}
' Input_file valFile
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                              ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                             ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  OFS=", "                         ##Setting OFS as comma space here.  
}
FNR==NR{                           ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be true when key values file is being read.
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){              ##Traversing through all fields here.
    match($i,/\047[^\047]*/)       ##Using match to match from single quote to next occurrence of single quote.
    value[++count]=substr($i,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)  ##Creating value with increasing value of count and its value is sub string of matched value.
  }
  next                             ##next will skip all statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){               ##Traversing through all fields here.
    if($i!=0 && $i!~/^-/){          ##Checking condition if field is NOT 0 and not starts from - then do following.
      val=(val?val OFS:"")value[$i]  ##Keep adding value of array in val here.
    }
  }
  print val                         ##Printing val here.
  val=""                            ##Nullifying val here.
}
' Input_file valFile                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a super solution!

Comment: @kaiserm99, Added explanation in solution too now, where Input_file is your file which has `['aaaaa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'dd', 'eeeee']` and `valFile` is your actual file, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR { 
                str=gensub(/[\[\]'"'"']/,"","g",$0);
                split(str,map,",") 
             } 
     NR != FNR { 
                for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
                                      if ( map[$i]!="") { 
                                                          printf "%s",map[$i] 
                                                        } 
                                      } 
                printf "\n" 
               }' fil1 fil2
```

One liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { str=gensub(/[\[\]'"'"']/,"","g",$0);split(str,map,",") } NR != FNR { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( map[$i]!="") { printf "%s",map[$i] } } printf "\n" }' fil1 fil2
```

Process both files. For the first file (NR==FNR) strip out the [, ] and then split the line into an array map with , as the delimiters. Then for the second file (NR!=FNR) loop through each space delimited field and if there is an entry in the map array, print it.

Comment: The answer has been amended

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your files are "f1" and "f2", respectively, this could be a solution in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=()
while read -d ',' L; do
        A+=("${L:1:-1}")
done <<< "$(cat f1 | tr -d '[]'),"

while read L; do
        while read -d ' ' P; do
                if ((P>0)); then
                        P=$((P-1))
                        echo -n "${A[$P]} "
                fi
        done <<< "$L"
        echo
done < f2
```

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
$ cat map.array
['aaaaa', 'bbb', 'cccc', 'dd', 'eeeee']

$ cat map.numbers
-1 2 -3 -4 -5 0
1 -2 3 4 -5 0
1 2 -3 4 5 0
```

One `awk` solution:

```
awk -v sep="'" '                                 # splitting first file on single quote is cleaner with an input variable

# for first file (FNR==NR) ...

FNR==NR { n=split($0,tmp,sep)                    # split line on single quotes; store results in the tmp[] array
          ndx=0                                  # init arr[] array index
          for ( i=2 ; i<n ; i=i+2 )              # we want the even numbered entries from the tmp[] array
              { ndx++                            # increment arr[] index
                arr[ndx]=tmp[i]                  # copy tmp[] element into arr[]
              }
           next
        }

# for second file ...

        { output=""                              # init output string
          pfx=""                                 # clear prefix string
          for ( i=1 ; i<=ndx ; i++ )             # loop through our arr[] indices
              if ( $i == i )                     # if the value in field # i matches the value of i, eg, 1 == 1
                 { output=output""pfx""arr[i]    # then build our output string
                   pfx=", "                      # set the prefix to ", " for follow-on fields of interest
                 }
           if ( length(output) > 0 )             # if we have something to output ...
              printf "%s\n", output              # printf it
        }
' map.array map.numbers
```

**NOTE**: Remove comments to declutter code.

The above generates:

```
bbb
aaaaa, cccc, dd
aaaaa, bbb, dd, eeeee
```